# Split string by first word and rest of it - Postgresql

Tags: regex, postgresql, split

I need to divide a string in two. Saving always the first word and the rest of the string in a variable.

I'm using `string_to_array()` like this

```
first_word := (string_to_array(full_phrase, ' '))[1];
rest_of_string := (string_to_array(full_phrase, first_word))[2];
```

I considered that I need to find the first word and then I could return the rest of the string starting at this word. But there is a case where a string starts with a word that repeats.

**Input:**

1. My name is ** my car is blue
2. Hello World Friends
3. Hello World Hello World

**Expected**

1. first_word = My, second_word=name is ** my car is blue
2. first_word = Hello, second_word=World Friends
3. first_word = Hello, second_word=World Hello World

**Actual**

1. first_word = My, second_word=name is **
2. first_word = Hello, second_word=World Friends
3. first_word = Hello, second_word=World

Is there some way easy to do this, for example a regex. Thank you.

Comment: Use the lighter-weight strpos + substr. `first_word := SUBSTR(full_phrase, 1, STRPOS(full_phrase, ' ')); rest_of_string := SUBSTR(full_phrase, STRPOS(full_phrase, ' ') + 1);`

Comment: good idea thanks, and what about let's say I want to get only the last word and the rest of the sentence?

Comment: That's a bit more difficult. You may need to reverse the string and use `strpos` to get the reversed index, then subtract that from the string length to get the actual index for the original string. If you're doing anything more complex than a simple "first word" then it may be better to use heavier weight functions. For example, if you use regex to split the string, you can combine all the "other" parts back to a single string by using `STRING_AGG`.

Comment: What about  `SELECT regexp_matches('My name is ** my car is blue', E'^\\s*(\\S+)(?:\\s+(.+))?');`?